# extracting particular number from a line consisting of several numbers using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

As i consists of line having several numbers ,but i need to extract only first 6 digit number

```
import re
out=['DOT/R9.4x                 4616542  rtpbuild   x. : 20171111184750 p4 p4burtd review','DOT/dex                 4609974  build      ~. : 20171108044757 p4 p4burtd review']
for item in out:
    line=re.findall(r'\d{7}',item)
    print(line)
```

i'm getting output as:

```
['4616542','2017111','1184750']
['4609974','2017110','8044757']
```

but actually i need output of only 1st 7digit number:

```
[4616542]
[4609974]
```

i dont need those remaining number which has been divided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `search` instead of `findall` if you are looking for the first occurrence:

```
for item in out:
    line=re.search(r'\b\d{7}\b',item)
    print(line.group(0))
```

Notice that `re.search` returns an `SRE_Match` object. Another option would be to extract the first value from the list returned by `findall`.

Edited: Using `\b` will avoid matching bigger numbers (thanks to @Jean).

Comment: even better: `r'\b\d{7}\b'` (word boundary) which avoids to match bigger numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It's a list. If you need the first item only, then you need index `[0]`:

```
line=re.findall(r'\d{7}',item)[0]
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit your snippet? Also, you can link the official documentation for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
out=['DOT/R9.4x                 4616542  rtpbuild   x. : 20171111184750 p4 p4burtd review','DOT/dex                 4609974  build      ~. : 20171108044757 p4 p4burtd review']
for item in out:
    line=re.findall(r'\d{7}',item)[0]
    print([int(line)])
```

Answer (score 0):

> > findall() finds *all* the matches and returns them as a list of
> >     strings, with each string representing one match.
>
> findall() returns a list(and lists are iterables) and returns str
>   objects. let's check :

```
import re
    out=['DOT/R9.4x                 4616542  rtpbuild   x. : 20171111184750 p4 p4burtd review','DOT/dex                 4609974  build      ~. : 20171108044757 p4 p4burtd review']
    for item in out:
        line=re.findall(r'\d{7}',item)
        for i in line:
            print(i)
```

output:

```
4616542
2017111
1184750
4609974
2017110
8044757
```

so instead of findall use re.search for first matches :

> One line solution:

```
print([re.search(r'\d{7}',item).group() for item in out])
```

output:

```
['4616542', '4609974']
```